# Mysql query doesnt send response via JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

So i have this query,

```
$sql="SELECT c.first_name, a.id, a.name, a.current_value,a.end_date from psf_customer c,
        psf_auctions a join psf_customer_bids b ON a.id=b.auction_id where c.user_id =b.user_id
        and TIMESTAMP (b.timestamp, '00:00:02') >= '$now' order by b.timestamp DESC";
```

`$now` here is a variable which has the following date, (Current date)

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which is being executed via

```
 $bids = $this->Db->addSQL($sql)->execute()->fetchArray();
```

and sending the response

```
return json_encode($bids);
```

but when i try to get the response,

```
 var data = JSON.parse(d);
              console.log(data);
```

this console prints nothing, the query is working fine on the database. i suspect the variable `$now` needs to be altered somehow?

Comment: EDIT: i changed $now to CURRENT_DATE and received the response. but i dont want current_date, rather i would like $now to work, because of time differences,

Comment: You are checking with timestamp so use `$now = time();`

Comment: Maybe you can use the mysql function `now()`..

Comment: Seems like your code is good. I think the date $now is not what you expect and the server date is not set as you think

Comment: this is exactly what i am saying, the code works fine when i replace $now with CURRENT_DATE, but that's not what i want. (since my current date is not equal to server time)

Comment: "the query is working fine on the database. i suspect the variable $now needs to be altered somehow?" — If the query works fine, why would `$now` need to be changed?

Comment: `current_date()` only returns the current date while `now()` returns the current date and time in timestampp datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT c.first_name, a.id, a.name, a.current_value,a.end_date from psf_customer c,
    psf_auctions a join psf_customer_bids b ON a.id=b.auction_id where c.user_id =b.user_id
    and TIMESTAMP (b.timestamp, '00:00:02') >= now() order by b.timestamp DESC";
```

Comment: I have replaced `$now` with `now()`